# blank prod build Webpack 4 react

Tags: reactjs, build, package.json, webpack-4

`dev` works fine but no matter what I try (similar on SO, Googling, tutorials, T&E) the prod build still displays blank. I was originally using `webpack-merge` with a split prod/dev setup but have regressed to try a simplest implementation which still isn't working.

```
webpack.config.js
   const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "anubis-ui",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Anubis UI",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "author": "ctx-nemo",
  "license": "MIT",
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./src/setupTests.js"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --hot --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "prettier": "prettier --write src/*.js src/**/*.js src/**/**/*.js",
    "test": "jest 'test.js'",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "hookrouter": "^1.2.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.5.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "4.1.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^5.6.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^8.0.9",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/cypress-axe": "0.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.15",
    "@types/react": "16.8.21",
    "@types/webpack": "4.4.34",
    "axe-core": "3.3.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "cypress": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-axe": "^3.1.1",
    "lint-staged": "^7.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "react-tabs": "^3.0.0",
    "react-tabulator": "^0.9.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.2.0",
    "simple-assign": "0.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "webpack": "4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "^0.1.11"
  }
}
```

index.html (src)

> ```
> <title>QBoss UI</title>   </head>
> ```

index.html (built)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="description" content="App description">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

    <title>QBoss UI</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

The dist file gets populated with the `index.html` and `main.js` but they display blank.

No errors are generated and the only warnings are around size limits.